# Can Excel 2013 print different PrintTitleRows to each page?

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I may be trying to do the impossible. What I need is to dynamically set the **PrintTitleRows** for each printed page in **Excel**. My worksheet is created dynamically and there are multiple *(yet similar)* sections of different row lengths and I want to show the *section name* and *description titles* on the top of the following page if the section overflows to multiple pages. The section names will *not* always be the same though the column titles will. The *section name* is on the row above the *description titles*.

[Section name and description titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZIvD.png)

Currently, I am calling my **PageSettings** sub and then executing the **ExportAsFixedFormat**, so I am guessing this can't be done.

I have spent the last few hours searching the Microsoft site, *Stackoverflow.com* and the web in general with no questions or hits related to this question.

Thanks in advance for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in *no* and is based on my experience. The **PrintTitleRows** and **PrintTitleColumns** are a one time setting which I did in my **PageSettings** sub. Once **ExportAsFixedFormat** starts running, it never hits the **PageSettings** sub again.

**PrintTitleRows** is a one time setting that places the *same* row (or rows) at the top of every printed page but I needed *different* rows.

The best I found way to achieve this is to add the necessary rows to the worksheet after each page break to make the report look the way I want when printed. I then hide these *header* rows from the user and display them when I print.